# Laravel Passport create clients programmatically

Tags: laravel, oauth, client, laravel-passport

Is there a way to create clients from user interface in Laravel? If I need to allow users to create and manage their own clients, how can I run "passport:client" in a function context in order to create a client on the fly?

I tried by making a OauthClient model and implementing a form that generates the client, but the so created clients are not recognized in requests (they are random strings of 40 characters).

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend looking at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/src/Console/ClientCommand.php) where the command is handled (and maybe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/valterlorran/35e167742b95fcc34ce609b299f53089))

There is no need to create an own model class! You can create new clients programmatically by using the `Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository` class. Simply take one of these options:

**Use dependency injection**

You can inject the ClientRepository class into your controller/route functions. E.g. in the `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('test', function (\Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository $clientRepository) {
    $clientRepository->create(null, 'MyTest', 'https://example.com/auth/callback');
});
```

**Use the app() helper**

In fact also dependency injection but callable from any place of your code, you can use the `app()` helper:

```
$clientRepository = app('Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository');
$client = $clientRepository->create(null, 'MyTest', 'https://example.com/auth/callback');
```